# Python: How to get distribution of time spent in a location

Tags: python, algorithm, distribution, histogram, text-processing

I have a big data file with location information on some users. The format is shown below:

```
   User      TimeStamp            Lat        Long
     A   2013-03-01 19:55:00     45.4565    65.6783
     A   2013-03-01 01:40:00     46.3121    -12.3456
     A   2013-03-02 11:25:00     23.1234    -85.3456
     A   2013-03-05 05:00:00     15.4565    32.1234
        ......   

     C   2013-03-01 19:55:00     44.4565    35.6783
     C   2013-03-03 11:20:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:25:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:30:00     16.4565    22.1234
     C   2013-03-03 11:50:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:55:00     19.4565    -25.1234
        ......
```

The timestamps are such that each line represents a location during the 5 minute interval. This data is for a one week period.

Now, what I want to do is to get a simple distribution (histogram) of the time spent in each location by one user per day for the whole one week period. So it would be a 0h to 24h plot of time spent in each location per day per user.

The second thing is similar to the one above but instead of considering the total time by one user per day, I would only consider continuous time spend. For example, for user C, I would consider the 2nd and 3rd line together as a 10 minute period but the 5th line where he is back in the same place would be a separate 5 minute period.

How would I do this in python? I am a newbie here and am kinda stuck here. I would guess that I could break the timestamp into day, hour, minutes and seconds do get these counts per day. But I am lost after that.

Comment: Do you have the `numpy` and `matplotlib` packages installed?

Comment: I would take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Yes. I have pandas installed as well along with numpy and matplotlib. Using any freely available libraries wont be a problem. Learning how to use them is what I need to learn  :)

Comment: @sfactor Did you arrive at a solution to this problem? If so, could you tell us about it?

Answer (score 1):

To gather the data:

For the first part (where we're not "fusing together" timestamps), maintain a map of

`(latitude, longitude) -> time spent`

process each timestamp, incrementing  the appropriate map entry.

For the second part:

Sort the timestamps first by user, then by time. Now you can run two "pointers" through the list, one for the beginning and the other for end of a continuous period.

Augment your map with a third "dimension", which could correspond to the beginning of the continuous period.

i.e.

`(latitude, longitude, beginning of period) -> time spent`

And, voila, add all timestamps in a continous period to the appropriate map entry.

Visualization is a different beast: one I have no clue on how to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a heatmap like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

content = '''\
   User      TimeStamp            Lat        Long
     A   2013-03-01 19:55:00     45.4565    65.6783
     A   2013-03-01 01:40:00     46.3121    -12.3456
     A   2013-03-02 11:25:00     23.1234    -85.3456
     A   2013-03-05 05:00:00     15.4565    32.1234
     C   2013-03-01 19:55:00     44.4565    35.6783
     C   2013-03-03 11:20:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:25:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:30:00     16.4565    22.1234
     C   2013-03-03 11:50:00     42.3121    -22.3456
     C   2013-03-03 11:55:00     19.4565    -25.1234
'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s+', parse_dates=True, index_col=[1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(df['User'].nunique())
for i, (user, grp) in enumerate(df.groupby('User')):
    xedges = np.linspace(grp['Long'].min(), grp['Long'].max(), 5)
    yedges = np.linspace(grp['Lat'].min(), grp['Lat'].max(), 7)        
    hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(
        grp['Long'], grp['Lat'], (xedges, yedges), normed=False)
    hist = hist.T
    print(hist)
    ax[i].pcolormesh(hist, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
    ax[i].set_xticks(np.arange(hist.shape[1]+1), minor=False)
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(map('{:0.2f}'.format, xedges), minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticks(np.arange(hist.shape[0]+1), minor=False)
    ax[i].set_yticklabels(map('{:0.2f}'.format, yedges), minor=False)
    ax[i].invert_yaxis()
    ax[i].set_xlim(0, hist.shape[1])
    ax[i].set_ylim(0, hist.shape[0])
    ax[i].set_title(user)
plt.show()
```

[image]